# .exe doesn't work apparently because of paths to files

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I made my own little game with pygame. I'm trying to make an .exe and an installer. I'm using cmd console to create an .exe. I'm typing

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w NameOfTheFile.py
```

or

```
pyinstaller --onefile NameOfTheFile.py
```

and the .exe indeed is created. In order to make the game independent of the commputer it is run at I used

```
PathToDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

to get the path to the current directory. Afterwards I write:

```
TloIMG = pygame.image.load(PathToDir+"\\Pictures\\Sceneria1.png")
```

to load the picture of the background and similarly with any other files. My game works in different directories and commputers, so the code is fine. But after creating an. exe it doesn't work. cmd console says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "Robocop.py", line 314, in <module>

TloIMG = pygame.image.load(PathToDir+"\\Pictures\\Sceneria1.png")

FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory.

[9780] Failed to execute script 'Robocop' due to unhandled exception!
```

Does anyone know what is wrong and how to create executable? :(

Comment: This `exe` file should work if you execute it from folder `A` and in folder `A` there is folder `Pictures` and in folder `Pictures` there is `Scenerial1.png`.

Comment: See [**Using \_\_file\_\_**](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-file) in the [Rᴜɴ-ᴛɪᴍᴇ Iɴғᴏʀᴍᴀᴛɪᴏɴ](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html) section of the fine PyInstaller documentation.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `--onefile` parameter it's not possible to use relative paths because `pyinstaller` unpacks the bundled data to a temporary folder, the path to the folder is stored in the `_MEIPASS` environment variable.

The following function should return the correct path for you whether it's executed within the executable or the development environment.

```
import sys
import os

def resource_path(relative_path):
    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

Comment: What is bundled data, bundled script etc?